# Formula VLOOKUP with dynamic lookup value

Tags: excel, vba, formula, cell, vlookup

I want to let the lookup vale of a vlookup dynamic with the loop counter, I tried:

```
WS1.Cells(4 + j - 1, 3 + ((i - 1) * 9)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & WS1.Cells(4 + j - 1, 4 + ((i - 1) * 9)) & ",WS2NAME!B:C,2,FALSE)"
```

I though that `" & WS1.Cells(4 + j - 1, 4 + ((i - 1) * 9)) & "` would return the cell name, (eg B3, D5, ...) but it returns blank when I run the macro in excel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using R1C1 referencing would be easier here:

```
WS1.Cells(4 + j - 1, 3 + ((i - 1) * 9)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],WS2NAME!C2:C3,2,FALSE)"
```

Comment: I tried, but it seems it cannot recognize the lookup array, in the printed formula I have: "=VLOOKUP(B4;Sheet!B:C:C;2;FALSE)"; it has added a "C" in the lookup array, it should be "Sheet!B:C"

Comment: What **actual** code did you use?

Comment: WS1.Cells(4 + j - 1 + (i - 1) * (var + 3), 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-1],WS2NAME!B:C,2,FALSE)"

Comment: That is not the code I posted. Please use exactly what I posted - you cannot use `B:C` in an R1C1 format.

Comment: Ah ok, but I need the lookup array on the whole B and C column, not just C2 and C3

Comment: Please **try** the code... ;) C2:C3 is the R1C1 equivalent of B:C in A1 reference style. (it stands for Column2:Column3)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it! It works, thanks!